# ASP.NET Core 5 OData: requesting an individual property not found

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-5.0

I am creating an OData service on .NET 5 using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData`.

In my EDM model there is a collection of reports that is based on the following entity type:

```
 <EntityType Name="Report">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="ReportId" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ReportId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="ReportName" Type="Edm.String" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="Units" Type="Collection(DataModelBase.UnitInfo)" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="Data" Type="Collection(DataModel.EntityInfo)" />
 </EntityType>
```

When I send the request `serviceRoot/Reports('1')`, I can see the report with `ReportId='1'` showing up correctly.

However, if I try `serviceRoot/Reports('1')/ReportId`, which should work according to the [OData Basic Tutorial](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#property), I get a 404 not found error.

My app configuration is as follows (F#):

```
app.UseRouting()
   .UseEndpoints(fun endpointBuilder ->
                endpointBuilder.MapControllers() |> ignore;
                endpointBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().Count().OrderBy() |> ignore;
                endpointBuilder.MapODataRoute("odata","odata",edmModel) |> ignore
            )|> ignore
```

And services:

```
services.AddControllers(fun mvcOptions -> mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting <- true) |> ignore;
services.AddOData() |> ignore
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I think I have the answer to my question: the parameter routes are not generated automatically like I expected them to be. You need to implement the controllers for the routes yourself.